# Biblatex: Can We Delete `\autocite` From Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

Why do we have two different commands for citing? One when citing exactly one source (`\autocite`) and another one that is conceived to be used when citing more than one source (`\autocites`)?

If you always use `\autocites` you dont have to make any changes regarding the command when you reduce or extend the references, because it seems to work with any number of references (including exactly one). If you use `\autocite` you have to make adjustments as soon as you change the number of sources. It seems as if `\autocite` could be eliminated because it is included in the `\autocites` command (or it could be redefined in a way that it works like the `\autocites`). (The same holds true for `\cite` etc.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@inbook{hC77a,
author = {Herbert~H. Clark},
title = {Inferences in Comprehension},
pages = {243-263},
booktitle = {Basic processes in Reading},
booksubtitle = {Perception and Comprehension},
editor = {David LaBerge and S.~Jay Samuels},
year = {1977},
location = {Erlbaum},
} 


  @book{jS09,
   author = {John~I. Saeed},
   title = {Semantics},
   subtitle = {},
   year = {2009},
   publisher = {Wiley-Blackwell},
   location = {Malden, Mass. [u.a.]},
   }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Using autocites \autocites[152-169]{jS09} % this does work

Using autocites \autocites[152-169]{jS09}[252]{hC77a} % this does work

Using autocite \autocite[152-169]{jS09}

Using autocite \autocite[152-169]{jS09}[252]{hC77a} % this doesnt work

\end{document}
```

So: Is there any hidden difference?

Comment: `\autocites` has a 'global' prenote and postnote.  I don't think this is a 'hidden' difference, since it is documented, but it is a significant difference.  I think the value of having `\autocite` and `\autocites` is that they follow an established `biblatex` pattern that is easy to remember.  Your suggestion would make it harder to remember the `biblatex` command name philosophy.  And you can of course do as you please through a combination of `\let` and `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Even if both commands were actually identical: having both commands means that you can be a more lazy while typing. I like it if commands and options exit in more than one variant and you can choose more intuitively a suitable variant for the current context.

Comment: @jon & Ulrike Fischer: I know little about programming. But I got the impression that one of the fundamental principles is the creation of a lean command structure.

The answers suggest that there are other reasons that guide command architecture such as name philosophy, mental capacities & choices. These dont feel entirely satisfying here. 

at jon: A reduced approach seems to make it easier to remember.

at Ulrike Fischer: Generally, I like choices too. In this case having a choice seems to be unnecessary. Why bother with context dependent decisions where you can have a universal command?

Comment: @Philip -- Well, to each, their own.  To me, and that's all I'm suggesting, it is easier to expect that all citation commands have a singular and plural form than that all but one citation commands do.  At any rate, if this is something you feel strongly about, it seems like a better place to raise the issue is on the [Github development page](https://github.com/plk/biblatex).  If you are simply asking 'why', I think my comment explains the underlying philosophy ... but that's just a guess. (In fact, I never use `\autocite` or any plural citation command, so it hardly matters to me.)

Comment: @jon: I would/will suggest that all commands being changed (if that doesnt have any other effects) in order to keep simplicity on the naming level and on the command level. And thank you for the link.

Comment: @Philip I wouldn't bother with the feature request at github. Details on why can be found in the answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short: No. `\cite` is a command used for generating *unqualified* citation lists. It follows the syntax:

```
\cite[<pre>][<post>]{<keys>}
```

This prints a list of citation labels for each of the entries specified in `<keys>` with a common prenote `<pre>` and postnote `<post>`. If `sortcites` is enabled, the citation list is sorted according to the order given by the load-time option setting `sorting`.

By default `\cites` is defined on the basis of `\cite` with:

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}{\cite}{\multicitedelim}
```

It follows the syntax:

```
\cites(<pre>)(<post>)[<pre 1>][<post 1>]{<keys 1>}...[<pre n>][<post n>]{<keys n>}
```

This applies the basic `\cite` command to each of the *n* unqualified citation lists whose entries are specified by `<keys 1>`, `<keys 2>`, ... `<keys n>`. The entire citation list is *qualified* by individual prenotes and postnotes `<pre 1>`, ..., `<pre n>`, `<post 1>`, ..., `<post n>` and is printed with an overall prenote `<pre>` and postnote `<post>`. When `sortcites` is enabled, citation labels are sorted only within the *n* unqualified lists.

Similar properties hold for other standard citation commands and their multicite variants (e.g. `\parencite` and `\parencites`, `\footcite` and `\footcites`) as well as style-dependent citation commands (e.g. `\textcite` and `\textcites`, `\smartcite` and `\smartcites`, `\supercite` and `\supercites`). `\autocite` and `\autocites` are "style-independent" commands defined on the basis of `\cite`, `\parencite`, `\footcite`, `\smartcite` or `\supercite`. These allow the user to make parenthetical-type citations and freely switch between citation styles.

Further details can be found in the biblatex user guide in the section called "Citation Commands".

Comment: Also `\autocites*` makes no sense but `\autocite*` is very useful.